# SparkStreaming throwing RpcEndpointNotFoundException error

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using SparkStreaming to read XML messages from a Qpid Queue. I use Receiver implementation to read the messages from the queue.

When I start the Application I keep getting below error, but I am able to read and process the XMLs.

Another error which keeps coming during the processing is:

**SparkException : Could not start receiver as object not found.**

Anyone encountered the same and able to resolve it?

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 7, localhost): org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointNotFoundException: Cannot find endpoint: spark://ReceiverTracker@localhost:53188
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$asyncSetupEndpointRefByURI$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$asyncSetupEndpointRefByURI$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:144)
```

Comment: Seems like there is a network problem connecting to the Netty endpoint spark initiates.

Comment: Could you show your codes?